# swiper element inside swiperComponent does not exists angular13

Tags: angular, swiper.js

i have imported `swiperComponent` in my appComponent in angular13:

```
import { SwiperComponent } from 'swiper/angular';
```

and imported in the class with `ViewChildren`:

```
  @ViewChildren('swiperSlideShow') swiperSlideShow!: QueryList<SwiperComponent>;
```

In the template i have:

```
<swiper [config]="config" #swiperSlideShow>
```

and when i log:

```
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log(this.swiperSlideShow.toArray()[0]);
    }
```

I get the swiper component as shown in this image
[image]

In the image is clearly visible the element swiper but when i try logging it in the console NPM trows an error which says that this property does not exist on the given object.

```
TS2551: Property 'swiper' does not exist on type 'SwiperComponent'.
```

Can anyone help me out in accessing this option?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention where did you put `console.log` statements. I assume they are inside `ngOnInit`.

When you look carefully at the screenshot of `console.log` output you'll notice little "i" icon. It means the value may have changed. DevTools uses lazy evaluation - the value you see is evaluated when you expand the tree, not when it's printed to the console. See: https://medium.com/young-coder/why-chromes-developer-console-sometimes-lies-9487e45e91ae

Second `console.log` yields `undefined` because at that time `swiper` is not yet defined.

Take a look at `swiper/angular` code. `swiper` is initialized inside  `ngAfterViewInit` hook.
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/b8b2681de24e9b0b98cfe644e09cf281311a24f5/src/angular/src/swiper.component.ts#L533-L540

---

After a few OP edits the main purpose changed. Finally its about `swiper` property not being exposed on `SwiperComponent` from `swiper/angular` package.

Comment: i am sorry, i wasn't precise, i am logging inside afterviewinit....

Comment: That would need deeper investigation in `swiper/angular` code. Maybe they run something asynchronously. Wrap your problematic `console.log(this.swiperSlideShow.toArray()[0].swiper);` with `setTimeout(() => {})` you should see swiper instance in the console

Comment: TS2551: Property 'swiper' does not exist on type 'SwiperComponent'.

Comment: Once more going back to `swiper/angular` -> https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/b8b2681de24e9b0b98cfe644e09cf281311a24f5/src/angular/src/swiper.component.ts

`SwiperComponent` doesn't expose `swiper` property (thus TS error). However it does expose output emitter called `swiper` which you can subscribe and receive swiper instance when it's ready to use.

Comment: i thank you very much for the attempt but it is still giving me undefined property when i try subscribing to it...

Comment: All you need is here https://swiperjs.com/angular#usage